# Different methods to square a value result in slightly different output - which method is most accurate / reliable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, math

I am getting (very occasionally) slightly different calculation results between C code and Python code, and managed to find an example. In Python, I get this:

```
>>> print "%.55f" %\
... (-2.499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875 *\
... -2.499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875)
6.2499999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875000000
>>> print "%.55f" %\
... ((-2.499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875) ** 2)
6.2499999999999973354647408996243029832839965820312500000
>>> print "%.55f" %\
... math.pow(-2.499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875, 2)
6.2499999999999973354647408996243029832839965820312500000
```

Whereas in C, the following program:

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("%.55f\n", -2.499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875\
    * -2.499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875);
    printf("%.55f\n",\
    pow(-2.499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875, 2));
    return 0;
}
```

gives the following result:

```
6.2499999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875000000
6.2499999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875000000
```

It gets worse. Running `bc -l`, I get the following:

```
-2.499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875 *\
-2.499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875 
6.249999999999997779553950749687116367962969071310727
```

This seems to be the correct result; [Casio's online high precision calculator](http://keisan.casio.com/calculator) agrees.

What worries me, however, is that `(var * var)`, `(var ** 2)` and `math.pow(var, 2)` occasionally give slightly different results (I am using Python 2.7.6).

Anyone know why?

Comment: So you don't want "best" you want "most accurate"? Over what range of values?

Comment: Just a thought that occurred to me:   is `-2.499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875 *    -2.499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875` behaving differently from `(-2.499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875) * -2.499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875`

Comment: (they are behaving identically on my computer)

Comment: What operating system, CPU, and Python version are you using?

Comment: @casevh Mac OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.2, 2.8 GHz Intel Core i7, Python 2.7.8. See my answer below, based mostly on your recommendations.

Comment: @Ben I just want it to be consistent. I understand I'll never have great precision using floats or doubles, but having `(v*v)` and `(v**2)` behaving differently is worrying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your answers, guys, I dug deeper thanks to them, and managed to understand a bit better what's going on. @casevh was correct, the problem is not with Python, but with the underlying C library.

I'm working with a Mac, and have installed gcc 5.0, which I used to compile the example C code I provided:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 5.0.0 20141005 (experimental)
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

But the python interpreter is using a different C compiler version:

```
Python 2.7.8 (v2.7.8:ee879c0ffa11, Jun 29 2014, 21:07:35) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
```

And the Apple provided C compiler is yet another version:

```
$ cc --version
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

As a matter of interest, I compiled the same C code using `cc`, and the output was:

```
6.2499999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875000000
6.2499999999999973354647408996243029832839965820312500000
```

So the problem is with the version of the C library provided with Macs. Python seems to use the pow function from the C math library for both `v ** 2` and `math.pow(v, 2)`.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that you are using floating point values, which by design are not *exact* or *precise* - a `float` in Python has just 53 significant bits. For what this means, I recommend you to read the article [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) or the slightly easier [What every computer programmer should know about floating point](http://blog.reverberate.org/2014/09/what-every-computer-programmer-should.html).

Though in case of Python, there is a rounding error too:

```
# incorrect one is:
>>> (6.2499999999999973354647408996243029832839965820312500000).hex()
'0x1.8fffffffffffdp+2'
>>> (6.2499999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875000000).hex()
'0x1.8fffffffffffep+2'
```

when the precise result would be

```
0x1.8fffffffffffd8000000000001p+2
```

Notice that the rounding error is that it is off by less than 2^-100 from the actual rounding point, that is:

```
0x1.8fffffffffffd8000000000000p+2
```

should be rounded up, whereas

```
0x1.8fffffffffffd7ffffffffffffp+2
```

should be rounded down. I guess that your *processor* rounds the value "incorrectly" there.

---

As for the C program, notice that the `pow(-2.499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875, 2)` being a constant value, it is completely eliminated, and thus the program can be linked without the `-lm` for math library; I suggest you try this part with
the value in a variable:

```
volatile double a = -2.499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875;
printf("%.55f", pow(a, 2));
```

which might provide a different result.

---

But Python also has an arbitrary precision decimal library, `decimal.Decimal`:

```
with localcontext() as ctx:
    # set the precision to 200 significant digits
    ctx.prec = 200
    result = decimal.Decimal(
       '2.499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875') ** 2)

print(result)
```

prints

```
6.24999999999999777955395074968711636796296907131072793214132069
6557418301608777255751192569732666015625
```

This is the correct result, not the one you got from `bc`; On my computer `bc -l` sets the scale to 20 significant digits, but it is adjustable with `scale` variable:

```
% bc
bc 1.06.95
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'. 
scale = 200 
2.499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875 * 2.499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875
6.249999999999997779553950749687116367962969071310727932141320696557\
418301608777255751192569732666015625
```

The result is the same as from Python. (notice that 100 is not enough precision, because the resulting value has 104 significant decimal digits).

---

You can check the digits by python too, without any imports - Python has arbitrary precision integer arithmetic too:

```
>>> 2499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875 * \
... 2499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875
624999999999999777955395074968711636796296907131072793214132069
6557418301608777255751192569732666015625L
```

---

In Python 3 you can also easily check the binary representation of a floating point number:

```
>>> (2.499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875).hex()
'0x1.3ffffffffffffp+1'
```

This number squared should have the same digits as the integer with same digits squared:

```
>>> hex(0x13ffffffffffff * 0x13ffffffffffff)
'0x18fffffffffffd8000000000001'
```

But clearly this is not representable exactly in just 53 significant bits; instead it requires twice the bits to be represented exactly:

```
>>> log2(0x13ffffffffffff * 0x13ffffffffffff)
104.64385618977472
```

Incidentally, because of `f`s, this is almost the same number of non-zero digits that are required for the decimal presentation:

```
>>> len('6249999999999997779553950749687116367962969071310727932141320696557418301608777255751192569732666015625')
103
```

Comment: Really informative answer, thank you very much. As a matter of interest, using a volatile variable still gives the same result, though.

Answer (score 1):

@AnttiHaapala explained why rounding needs to occur - the result requires more than 53 bits for an exact result. Ideally, you would get the same result for all three versions of the calculation. They *should* all round to the same value. But not all operating systems and compilers compute a correctly rounded result.

I happen to get the same answers for all three versions.

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 20 2014, 15:05:19) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import math
>>> a=-2.499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875
>>> print "%.55f" % (a*a)
6.2499999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875000000
>>> print "%.55f" % (a**2)
6.2499999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875000000
>>> print "%.55f" % (math.pow(a,2))
6.2499999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875000000
```

Python just uses what the operating system and compiler provide. For binary floating point calculations, the [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/) library does guarantee correctly rounded results. MPFR is used by GCC to evaluate constant expressions at compile time.

I maintain the [gmpy2](https://code.google.com/p/gmpy/) extension module which provides access to the MPFR library from Python.

Comment: me too, but I am running the exactly same Ubuntu 14.10 python

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I have seen different results between 32-bit and 64-bit builds made with the same compiler and on the same CPU. I think this is caused by the differences between the old x87 (80-bit long double) and the more recent SSE (64-bit double) instructions and which particular instructions are used. BTW, I'm using an AMD Phenom II.

Comment: I cannot trigger the incorrect rounding in any way that I try (for example with -m32)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala What CPU do you have? Are you using the same test code I used?

Comment: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3120M CPU @ 2.50GHz and Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E8400  @ 3.00GHz, always correct result (...875) from python pow